# How to introduce a custom testing phase in Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, spock

I would like to introduce a separate testing phase for spock specifications located in a separate directory. Theses tests are mainly long runners and will be executed during nightly builds.

For Grails 2.x I found this blog: http://ldaley.com/post/615966534/custom-grails-test, but in Grails 3.x there is no _Event.groovy anymore.

Is there a way to introduce a custom testing phase, like

```
grails test-app -custom
```

The test cases within the custom phase should run like the integration tests with full access to the application, hibernate session and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can write your tests in a separate module (i.e. big-tests) and run them using a gradle task for your module that contains your "small" tests, you could end up with a estructure like:

```
project
   your-api
   big-tests
```

Running your api tests
gradle :your-api:test

Running your big tests
gradle :big-tests:test

Comment: Tried to create a separate sub-directory within my project containing the spock specifications, but got following gradle error: Project 'big-test' not found in root project 'mcc'.

Comment: Following approach worked for me: I created a package directory under:
- integration-test
-- bulk
--- MySpec.groovy (package bulk)

In this case I moved all long runners to this package and executed the tests with the include pattern: grails test-app bulk.* -integration. All other tests are executed like:  grails test-app other.* -integration.

Comment: The first error can be solved adding big-test on settings.gradle file

Comment: Anyhow, glad to hear that you have working your specs as you wanted :)